# Multiple Joins in SQL with aliases

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this statement

```
Select b.Username
from TableA as a
left join TableB as b on a.UserID = b.UserID
```

Now I want join another table with b.Username in the same SQL statement

This SQL doesn't work (I have marked the part where it doesn't work with **):

Error Message

> the multi-part identifier could not be bound

```
Select b.Username, c.Adress
from TableA as a
left join TableB as b on a.UserID = b.UserID
left join TableC as c on c.Username = **b.Username**
```

Hope you can help me

Comment: Could you please explain "does not work". I suspect you have got some b.Username=NULL

Comment: i got this error message the multi-part identifier could not be bound

Comment: I can't replicate your problem. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d840c6a7550075b3e3196f7f65be2a46). Post a full [mre].

Comment: @24ngusl Please provide your table structure of all three tables. Usually this message says, that the column you are using does not exist in your table. So I'd say either `c.UserName` or `b.UserName` does not exist

Comment: @Larnu [This Badger](https://www.badgerbadgerbadger.com/)?

Answer (score -1):

Though there is no reason for your query to fail please try the query without aliases:

```
Select TableB.Username, TableC.Adress
from TableA 
left join TableB on TableA.UserID = TableB.UserID
left join TableC on TableC.Username = TableB.Username
```

Comment: This, by the DBMS, would be parsed identically.

Comment: Yup. There should not be any differences.